# How does the NSTextView make the text in the middle of the line

Tags: swift, macos, nstextview

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    @IBOutlet var editView: NSTextView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        let
        paragraphStyle = NSParagraphStyle.default().mutableCopy() as! NSMutableParagraphStyle
        paragraphStyle.lineHeightMultiple = 1.6
        editView.defaultParagraphStyle = paragraphStyle;
        //editView.typingAttributes[NSFontAttributeName] = paragraphStyle;
        editView.typingAttributes[NSParagraphStyleAttributeName] = paragraphStyle;

    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }
}
```

This is all my code, in main.storyboard, there's only one NSTextView control.

But my text is drawn, and it's all started at the bottom of the row, which is not what I want. I want to be able to keep the text in the vertical position of the row. I have not found a case in this area, please help me answer. thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use NSAttributedStringKey.baselineOffset (NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName in Swift 3) to adjust the vertical position of the text within the line. You will of course need to write a little code to calculate your line height and find the correct baseline to use, but this code sample should give you the basic idea:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    @IBOutlet var editView: NSTextView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        let paragraphStyle = NSParagraphStyle.default.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableParagraphStyle
        paragraphStyle.lineHeightMultiple = 1.6
        editView.defaultParagraphStyle = paragraphStyle
        editView.typingAttributes[.paragraphStyle] = paragraphStyle
        editView.typingAttributes[.baselineOffset] = 15
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
            // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: BaselineOffset can achieve this, but it will make the lineHeightMultiple more difficult to control, because the actual height is lineHeightMultiple + baselineOffset, is there any other convenient way?